# jquery autocomplete search by lowercase

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I wanna work jquery autocomplete plugin with lowercase. The array includes uppercase, lowercase words. Bu when I write text in textbox, the jquery should convert to lowercase that text and convert the array words to lowercase then match words.

```
var names = [{
    value: "1",
    label: "Jon Kerer"},
{
    value: "2",
    label: "Scott MART"},
{
    value: "3",
    label: "Sel HURGE"}
];​

$("#myInput").autocomplete({
    focus: ..... ? 
    select : .... ? 
    source : ... ?
});​
```

Comment: so you want to make the autocomplete case-insensitive? Guess what? It is already case insensitive! http://jsfiddle.net/Gs6hm/ try to write the uppercase stuff lowercase and vice-versa

Comment: var names array includes different country spesific names. Turkish, Japan, Korean, .... so all countries names include spesific charecters. (Şak, Örn, örn, ález) so the jquery can not find all names.

Comment: Have you seen the accent folding demo? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#folding Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a character map and do some parsing of the names. This is just a starter list of some characters. You could try some of the globalization libraries to locate a complete set

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/uQK5s/

```
var accentMap = {
    "á": "a",
    "ö": "o",
    "Ş": "S",
    "á": "a"
};
var normalize = function(term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
        ret += accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};

$("#test").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response($.grep(names, function(value) {
            value = value.label || value.value || value;
            return matcher.test(value) || matcher.test(normalize(value));
        }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toLowerCase() to convert a string to lowercase:

```
var string = 'Test String';
string = string.toLowerCase(); //string is now 'test string'
```

I'm not sure on how you are 'matching' words but you should be able to use the same function for the value in the array, then compare/match as you wish.

Comment: var names array includes different country spesific names. Turkish, Japan, Korean, .... so all countries names include spesific charecters. (Şak, Örn, örn, ález) so the jquery can not find all names.