# Using accentMap method of autocomplete with greek characters

Tags: jquery, encoding, autocomplete

little knowledge of jQuery and stuck with this. I am trying to employ the accentMap method of the autocomplete function for a json encoded array of greek characters. What I am eventually trying to achieve is this: **The user enters latin characters in the searchbox but the autocomplete maps them accordingly and suggests the greek entries of the array.** This is what I have:

My PHP array variable `$array` echoed:

```
Array ( [0] => ΩΦΧ [1] => ΓΔΕ )
```

My json encoded array via:

```
$array_json = json_encode($array);
```

My relevant DOM elements:

```
<input class="search-class" type="search" id="search-id"/>

<div id="autocomplete"><?php echo $array_json; ?></div>
```

My Jquery script, replicated from [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding):

```
jQuery(function() {
    var autocompleteData = jQuery('#autocomplete').text();

    var accentMap = {
      "ω": "w",
      "φ": "f",
      "χ": "x",
      "γ": "g",
      "δ": "d",
      "ε": "e"
    };

    var normalize = function( term ) {
      var ret = "";
      for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };

    jQuery( "#search-id" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( jQuery.grep( jQuery.parseJSON(autocompleteData), function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;
          return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
        }) );
      }
    });
  });
```

For the record, the autocomplete works fine with greek input characters.

I have tried re-arranging the order of the accentmap (i.e. "latin": "greek") or using `$array_json = utf8_encode(json_encode($array));` without any luck.

I believe the problem lies within the json encoding step. If I modify this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQK5s/) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188832/jquery-autocomplete-search-by-lowercase/11189473#11189473) with greek characters it all works fine. But in this jsfiddle the json encoding step is missing, hence my feeling that the problem lies there...

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out after all. It was extremely easy..

In case anyone has a similar problem, I just replaced the greek characters of the accentMap with their unicode codes and it all worked fine.